# 何とも Usage and Meaning

Tags: words, particles

> 4. 象は 大きい。
> 5. 象は おりに入れた。
> 6. 象は えさをやった。
> 7. 象は 鼻が長い。
>
> などの文では、「象は」はいずれも題目を示している。4の「象は」は「象が」に言い換えられるもので、事実上は文の主語を兼ねる。しかし、5以下は「象が」には言い換えられない。5は「象を」のことであり、6は「象に」のことである。さらに、7の「象は」は何とも言い換えられないものである（「象の」に言い換えられるともいう[47]）。これらの「象は」という題目は、「が」「に」「を」などの特定の格を表すものではなく、「私は象について述べる」ということだけをまず明示する役目を持つものである。

The above is a snippet from the Japanese Wikipedia page on Japanese which I am reading for Practise and bettering my understanding at the same time, especially on grammar. I am having trouble understanding 「何とも」 here within a sentence from the above snippet:

> さらに、7の「象は」は何とも言い換えられないものである

I can understand its meaning given the context, where it effectively says that "Sentence 7's [象は] is unable to be said any other way" (i.e. you cannot change the particle). But I fail to grasp a detailed understanding of 何とも in the sense that I know what it means (I have found many english "translations" of the word), but I fail to find any good explanations of how the expression actually works, as in are the 「と」and 「も」 particles? I think they must be obviously, but is the 「と」here the quotation particle or the inclusion particle etc.

I would appreciate it a lot if you anyone could shed light on the origin of the word with the particles which explain its meaning as it is the only way I will be able to fully understand it.

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「（～～を）XX**と**言い換える」 means "paraphrase ~~ **as** XX".
「**何も**・・・ない」 means "not ... **anything**" or "nothing".

The case particle と here functions like "as" in "rephrase something *as*~~" or "with" in "replace/exchange something *with*~~". eg 「切れた電球を新しいもの**と**取り替える」("replace a dead light bulb *with* a new one").

The adverbial/binding particle も, used with a negative word (「ない」), functions as "any". eg 「何**も**知らない」("don't know *any*thing") 「どこに**も**行かない」("don't go *any*where").

So 「（～～を）**何とも**言い換えられない」 means "cannot paraphrase ～～ **as anything**."

> さらに、7の「象は」は［何とも言い換えられない］ものである。

Here, 何とも言い換えられない modifies もの.

> *lit.* "Besides, the '象は' in #7 is something [that you cannot paraphrase as anything]."
>   → "Besides, the '象は' in #7 cannot be paraphrased as anything. / cannot be replaced by any other word."

Comment: Thank you, I believe I understand it now in terms of particles. You explanation has been great! Thank you!